# UITableView resize content width

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Someone change content width in my tabels after run) I dont touch this project about 2 months, it was ok. Now I build it and see that width of components resizing!!! Just opened and builded! Why that happens? Using AutoLayout, no warnings.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using constraints ?

Comment: Can you show constraints for this view?

Comment: @sloik yes, look at updated description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use constraints you should check your leading and trailing constraints before you add it

[image]

because if u uncheck(constrain to margin) u can can see another value

[image]

and compare leading&trailing constraint constants of you objects with different width size (constants should be identical)

Comment: with checked I have -8 -8 -8, with unchecked 0 0 0

Comment: I delete old constraints and add it with unchecked "constrain to migrations"its work for me. thx!